# Can I marry my cousin sisters husbands niece?

Tags: nikah, mahram

I fell in love with my father's sister's daughter's husband's niece, I really want to marry her, is she mahram for me? can I marry her?

Comment: Yes.Yes you can as she's not a close relative of yours. She is not considered as a close relative and you're not considered her mahram. Therefore, she is still a woman who needs to wear hijab in front of you and cannot be alone with you before marriage.